# Scraping a website after expending the content with selenium and beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am fairly new to `scrape` data from a webpage using `python`.
I tried to use `beautiful soup` to extract the data and was somewhat successful. However, I realized that certain elements are not included in my retrieved list and later in my `data frame`.

Therefore I tried to `expand` all fields before `scraping` the data with `beautiful soup`. I have now two parts of codes which work individually, but can't connect them. I can expand the fields, and I can retrieve data but without the content which are hidden "below the extensions" What I want to accomplish is to expand the fields and than scrape the complete content of the respective page. This is what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
```

please adjust the following as per your own webdriver (Internet explorer, Chrome, Firefox) and the actual path of the driver on your computer

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
```

adjust as per stock market symbol (STMS)

```
ticker_list = ["MSFT"]
for ticker in ticker_list:
    url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/financials?p={}".format(ticker, ticker)
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3600).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@data-test='qsp-financial']//span[text()='Expand All']"))).click()
```

And the seperate scraper which works with the origial link but not the above "extened link"

```
read_data = ur.urlopen(url_is).read()
soup_is= BeautifulSoup(read_data,"lxml")
ls= []
for l in soup_is.find_all("div" and "span"):
    ls.append(l.string)
ls = [e for e in ls if e not in ("Operating Expenses","Non-recurring Events")]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where's the question?

Comment: Hi Kristian, sorry if I did not make myself clear enough. I want to find a way how to use scrape the data from the webpage after extending all fields to get all the information which are currently hidden. Currently, I am just able to extend the fields with the above code. But cannot connect scraper with the the extend all bot

Answer (score 1):

Put your second code inside `for ticker in ticker_list` loop, then do the following steps:

1. Remove this line: `read_data = ur.urlopen(url_is).read()`.
2. Replace this: `soup_is = BeautifulSoup(read_data,"lxml")`,
   By this : `soup_is = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")`

And ofc the **lxml** library must be installed.